# OnGetColors event not firing for TColorBox

Tags: delphi, colors

I am trying to add a custom color to a `TColorBox` control. I've added the control to my form and for the `Style` property, set `cbCustomColor` to True. For the `OnGetColors` event, I have the following code:

```
procedure TfrmAbout.GetColors(Sender: TCustomColorBox; Items: TStrings);
begin
  ShowMessage('GetColors has been triggered');
  Items.AddObject('clWebSnow',TObject(clWebSnow));
  Items.AddObject('MyOrange',TObject(Rgb(255,128,0)));
end;
```

I don't see the messagebox or the colors appearing in the dropdown. Is there anything else I need to do in order to get this to work?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCustomColorBox.OnGetColors

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TColorBox

Comment: Surely you mean `TColorBox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get this to work I did have to follow @Sertac's suggestion. On FormCreate, I fired a procedure that removed the `[cbCustomColors]` then added them back in, for each TColorBox.

I could not find another suitable work around or figure out why GetColors was not firing when it should.

Answer (score 5):

You need to include the `cbCustomColors` option to the `Style` property to enable adding of your own custom colors instead. The `cbCustomColor` option only includes the item, which allows you to select a custom color.

Comment: Yes, I had stated that this was set to true, which is why this is puzzling me. Is there anything else that needs to be changed to fire that event?

Comment: @ika - Note the `s` at the end: `cbCustomColors`

Comment: ok yes that was a typo on my part. i have 's' at the end, the other option is to allow "Custom..." option in the dropdown to open the custom color dialog. With both even set to true even, I don't get that event.

Comment: @ika - I don't know what's wrong with your setup, but put (copy/paste) the following two lines in a button handler: `ColorBox.Style:=ColorBox.Style-[cbCustomColors];` `ColorBox.Style:=ColorBox.Style+[cbCustomColors];` and then click the button. See if your message pops up.

Comment: it does fire and the colors are added. so the question(s) are: why/how can I trick that event to fire, without having to press a button?

Comment: because i have like 11 `TColorBoxes` that all need these custom colors added, so I connected them all the to the same OnGetColors event...

Comment: The event does fire. Even if you have 11 color boxes. Your problem is that you are setting `cbCustomColor` to `True` rather than `cbCustomColors`. They are not the same. The design of this control is very confusing.

Comment: @ika - I don't understand, you can put those two lines anywhere you like. When do you want the event to fire? If you set the style at design time it fires after the combobox window of the colorbox is created.

Comment: I guess the question is in which event can I place that code to remove the `cbCustomColors` the add it back (because that seems to fix this weird problem)? I guess I need it to fire when the control is created.

Comment: Simply set the `cbCustomColors` option to True at design time in Object Inspector. The `OnGetColors` will be then fired when the component is created.

Comment: @ika - Did you even tried to put a TColorBox on *a brand new project*, set `cbCustomColors` to 'true', attach an event handler to `OnGetColors` and then run the application to see if the even is fired?

Comment: TLama, that has already been attempted. @Sertac, yes and I get the same result.

Comment: @ika - The only conclusion I can draw is that the component has a defect with your delphi version. I guess I'd try the form's OnShow event to set the style, together setting with a boolean flag perhaps so that the event is not fired everytime OnShow is fired..

Comment: I agree, thanks for the guided troubleshooting process. I was surprised/disappointed that the event fired when we tried that button click event code.

Comment: How are you creating those `TColorBox` objects ? If in code, then note that it's too late to create the object and then assign the `OnGetColors` event because the list of colors is populated (with this event to be fired) at component creation and then only if you change the `Style` property. In other words, it's too late to create a `TColorBox` object (e.g. `ColorBox := TColorBox.Create`) and then assign a common `OnGetColors` event method (e.g. `ColorBox.OnGetColors := CommonGetColors`) without changing the `ColorBox.Style` after.

Comment: If you're doing so, then you have to do something [like this](http://pastebin.com/7RucCBcY).